# How to force merge (with conflict markers) in JGit?

Tags: merge, jgit

Our application needs to use different merge strategies when fetching / merging with JGit. For instance, for any files in conflict that are JSON files, we want to revert any local changes and get THEIRS. If they're not JSON files, we want to keep local changes and merge, even keeping the conflict markers if there are conflicts. However, no matter how I set the merge strategy, I get a CheckoutConflictException (which stops the merge) even if normal command-line git would have done the merge. What am I doing wrong?

```
public String update() throws Exception {
    // We fetch manually and do a dry-run merge to catch any conflicts, so we can reset them

    fetch();
    Ref fetchHead = this.repo().getRepository().findRef("FETCH_HEAD");

    try {
        MergeResult mergeResult = this.repo().merge()
            .setStrategy(MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE)
            .setCommit(false)
            .setFastForward(MergeCommand.FastForwardMode.FF)
            .include(fetchHead)
            .call();
    } catch (CheckoutConflictException cce) {
        List<String> conflicts = cce.getConflictingPaths();

        if (conflicts != null && conflicts.size() > 0) {
            for (String file : conflicts) {
                if (file.endsWith(".json")) {
                    revert(Paths.get(file));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// ... and now that we've reverted any conflicted JSON files, we can try the merge for real

    MergeResult mergeResult = this.repo().merge()
        .setStrategy(MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE)
        .setCommit(true)
        .setFastForward(MergeCommand.FastForwardMode.FF)
        .include(fetchHead)
        .call();

    return mergeResult.getMergeStatus().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the behavior I wanted using stashCreate() and stashApply(). Specifically, stashCreate() to stash any changes left after reverting any JSON files, then using PullCommand (not MergeCommand) to pull any new changes, then using stashApply() to apply any stashed local changes. I tested it with no conflicts, conflicts in JSON files, conflicts in other files where different parts of the file were changed between local and remote, and other files where the same line(s) were changed. It worked in all of the above cases.